# How to pass value between two jframes

Tags: java, swing

I have two `jframes`,
I want to get value from opened another `jframe` to other opened `jframe`.
when click `jframe1` `open` button showing `jframe2` and type some text in text field and click `ok` button, text field value want to get `jframe1` `jlable`.  how to do this i tried but i can't find a way to do this.

Is this possible ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: use a call back interface between those 2 jframes...

Comment: Use [JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: @Ashan Another JFrame from where you have created  ? can you post little bit more code so that we can help you ?

Comment: at this situation jOptionPane not a solution @SergiyMedvynskyy :( thank you

Comment: this is same project. when open button click then jframe2 opening. when type some text and click ok button. jframe2 dispose and value must me set jframe1 lable. not closing jframe1 when click open.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) As suggested by @SergiyMedvynskyy, an option pane input dialog seems well suited to replace the 2nd frame.

Comment: how to use call back @Xoce please give me useful example link. thank you

Comment: *"at this situation jOptionPane not a solution"* ..why?

Comment: I have different project. it's using little complex two jframes. because why jOptionPane can't handle my problem i think.  @AndrewThompson

Comment: Use a modal dialog, which will block your codes execution until the window is closed, at which time you can use a getter to get the value from the other class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class TestFrameExample extends JFrame  implements ActionListener{
    static JLabel label ; 
    public static TestFrameExample test;
    TestFrameExample()
   {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      label = new JLabel("This is a label!");
      JButton button = new JButton("Open");
      button.setText("Press me");
      button.addActionListener(this);
      panel.add(label);
      panel.add(button);
      add(panel);
      setSize(300, 300);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
  }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
   {
          new TestFrameExample1();
  }
  public static void main(String s[]) {
      test=new TestFrameExample();
  }
}

class TestFrameExample1 extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {
  JTextField t;
  TestFrameExample test;
  public TestFrameExample1()
  {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        t=new JTextField();
        t.setBounds(100,20,150,20);
        JButton button=new JButton("oK");
        button.setBounds(100,50,100,30);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(t);
        add(button);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
   {
        test.label.setText(t.getText());
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a callback,

add this code to your project:

## Define an interface

```
public interface ICallbackListener{
    void onNewEvent(String msg);
}
```

---

## add to jframe 2:

```
private ICallbackListener myListener;
public void addCallback(ICallbackListener myListener){
    this.myListener = myListener;
}


...
if(myListener!=null){
myListener.onNewEvent("myMessage");
}
...
```

---

## add to jframe 1:

```
private ICallbackListener myListener;

ICallbackListener i = new ICallbackListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onNewEvent(String msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
        };
        
public void setCallback( ){
    jframe2.addCallback(myListener);
}
```

now, every thime the jframe2 call the interface method you will get asynchronous a call to the TODO label in the jframe1

Comment: Or simply use a modal dialog and wait for it to be closed

Comment: `public void setCallback( ){
    jframe.addCallback(myListener);
}`

what jframe to add this callback ???

Answer (score 0):

create a method that takes jframe1 in the jframe2 
in the open button action event create a object from jframe2 and call that method that take jframe1.

so when u click Ok button in the jframe2 pass that text field value to the jframe1 object (that u passed to the jframe2) via a methdo

```
public class jframe1 {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
     jfame2 jf2 = new jframe2();
     jf2.setJframe1(this);
  }
  public void updateLable(String value){
     lblIdk.setText(value);
  }
}


public class jframe2 {
  private jframe1 jf1;
  public void setJframe1(jframe1 jf1){
     this.jf1 = jf1;
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
     this.jf1.updateLable(txtidk.getText());
  }
}
```